# ArcGIS Pro Python Toolbox - env.workspace being 'forgotten' after using Spatial Analyst tools

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-3, error-000732

## EDIT

I've narrowed down the cause of the problem to the spatial analyst toolbox. After using an SA tool, arcpy seems to temporarily 'forget' the env.workspace setting: Subsequent attempts to reference datasets within the workspace using *relative* paths causes Error 000732 - Dataset does not exist. Very strangely, simply calling arcpy.env.workspace after using an SA tool seems to fix it.

See below for a (I hope) simple reproduce able example toolbox. I've tested it on two computers (running ArcGIS Pro 2.5.1 and 2.5.2). This tool:

1. Creates an new GDB, sets it as arcpy.env.workspace, and copies the input feature into it
2. Copies the features again (this time using a copied features in the GDB as the input)
3. Runs the slope tool on the input raster
4. Iterates over steps 2 and 3

The first iteration always works, but fails at step 2 on the second iteration. Really which tools are used doesn't matter, just chose copy and slope for simplicity in this example. The key part seems to be including a tool from the Spatial Analyst toolbox.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [Tool]

class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Tool"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        # Directory in which to create output geodatabase
        out_dir = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Output GDB Folder Location",
            name="Output GDB folder location",
            datatype="DEFolder",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        # Name for output geodatabse
        out_name = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Output GDB Name",
            name="Name of output GDB",
            datatype="GPString",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        # Input features class or shapefile.
        in_features = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input Features",
            name="Input Features",
            datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input"
        )
        # Input raster - ideally a DEM but doesn't really matter
        in_raster = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input Raster",
            name="Input Raster",
            datatype=["GPRasterLayer"],
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")


        params = [out_dir, out_name, in_features, in_raster]
        return params

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""
        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

        out_dir = parameters[0].valueAsText
        out_gdb_name = parameters[1].valueAsText
        features = parameters[2].valueAsText
        raster = parameters[3].valueAsText

        arcpy.AddMessage(f"out_dir = {out_dir}")
        arcpy.AddMessage(f"out_gdb_name = {out_gdb_name}")
        arcpy.AddMessage(f"features = {features}")
        arcpy.AddMessage(f"raster = {raster}")

        # Create output geodatabase
        geodatabase = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(out_dir, out_gdb_name).getOutput(0)
        arcpy.AddMessage(f"geodatabse = {geodatabase}")
        arcpy.env.workspace = geodatabase

        # Copy the features into the geodatabase (use basename in case input is .shp)
        features_basename = arcpy.Describe(features).basename
        features_copy = f"{features_basename}_copy"
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(features,features_copy)
        arcpy.AddMessage(f"features_copy = {features_copy}")


        for value in range(0,3):
            query = f'"test_field" = {value}'

            # Attempting to copy the buffered features (which exist within the env.workspace gdb) fails after first iteration)
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(features_copy, f"{features_copy}_{value}")

            # However, copying the original features (not in the geodatabse) still works
            # arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(features, f"{features}_{value}")

            # Spatial analyst tools seem to be what is causing it to 'forget' the workspace
            # Comment out these lines and the copy tool above runs fine ...
            slope = Slope(raster)
            slope.save(f"slope_{value}")

            # But simply 'printing' arcpy.env.workspace makes it 'remember' ....
            # arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.env.workspace)

        return
```

## ORIGINAL POST

#### Cleaned up for clarity

I'm writing a Python toolbox for ArcGIS Pro and having problems with the workspace environment setting. In short, when using *relative* paths to specify an input dataset within a workspace, ArcPy geoprocessing tools sometimes return an error saying that the input dataset does not exist. Strangely, simply printing `arcpy.env.workspace` using `arcpy.AddMessage()` immediately before the tool that was failing seems to fix the issue. This, however, doesn't seem like a good solution - it seems like there are bigger issues with the environment setting being honored inconsistently. Any ideas what could be going wrong?

I *know* the dataset does exist (it worked the first time, after all)  so I suspected that somewhere in my code, env.workspace was being 'unset' or overwritten to a different value. However, this also seems impossible, as I only set env.workspace *once* at the very beginning of my script.

To check this I added `arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.env.workpace)` so I could examine it's value immediately before the geoprocessing tool that was failing. As I suspected, env.workspace was still set correctly. **But to my surprise, this also fixed the problem: now the tool successfully finds the input dataset and runs without problems**. It's as though ArcPy is temporarily 'forgetting' that environment setting and then 'remembering' it again when I print it out. But printing it out A) shouldn't reassign it's value and B) just confirms that it was assigned properly in the first place.

This never seems to be an issue for the output dataset - in that case the environment setting is always honored. I've also been having issues with the env.overwriteOutput settting, [similar to what is described in this geonet post](https://community.esri.com/thread/236217-envoverwriteoutput-not-working-after-upgrade-to-pro-24). I wonder if the two could be related?

Comment: Just an idea, accept that there is a bug and use `in_features= arcpy.env.workspace + '\\my_features'`?

Comment: Yeah that does work, or similarly using `os.path.join`, but I'm trying to get around doing that in every single instance. I feel like it makes the code less readable, and it just seems like not having to do that is kinda the point of `env.workspace`, right

Comment: @user2856 sorry I'll edit that snippet when I'm back at my desk - I added the kwarg names after the fact and apparently screwed them up. But no it does not actually replicate the same issue, it was more just to illustrate the basic concept. Unfortunately I can't post the exact code I'm working on,  i'm trying to figure out how to replicate it ... But once I do I'll likely have my answer ;)

Comment: @user2856 Yeah I understand, I'm just not sure what I exactly i need to do to replicate the issue ... Working on it though, will update if I figure it out

Comment: @user2856 I've edit the post to include a reproduce-able example that can be copy-pasted into a .pyt file. If you have time to look at it I would love to hear your thoughts, and please let me know if you have problems running it. At this point I have a work-around for my issue, so it's not so much about getting my code running ... but I think this may be a bug with arcpy and would like to see if others can reproduce it